# Splitting up HTML in javascript to store in a DB

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to split up a block of HTML from an old site to store in a db. I am using Node.js with a jQuery plugin to do the basic splitting, but there are 3 parts I can not split up.

1) A product id, which sits in an url. This id starts after the last / and stops before the following -

2) A price, which starts after the first ; and stops before the following " " (space)

3) A name, which starts after the first > and stops before this string " item listing"

I don't to have people do my work for me, but I do now know how to start by figuring out how to come up with a regex for these situations. Maybe a push in the right direction will be enough.

```
<a href="privateurl/2332/32322-product-name-blah">
<div>
    <span>Product Name Blah item listing</span>
    <div>
        <span>
            Our price:<br />
            &#36;0.25 USD
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
```

It is simplified a little, but you can the the ids, names, and prices I need to split out.

Comment: IF you can provide examples of the actual html or a mock of it would probably help.

Comment: Would it be fine with a solution without regex?

Comment: I will post an example within the next 5 mins, and a solution without the use of regex would be fine, but I assume a regex would have the best performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = '<a href="privateurl/2332/32322-product-name-blah">\n\
<div>\n\
    <span>Product Name Blah item listing</span>\n\
    <div>\n\
        <span>\n\
            Our price:<br />\n\
            &#36;0.25 USD\n\
        </span>\n\
    </div>\n\
</div>\n\
</a>';

s.match(/\/([^/-]*)-(?!.*\/.*)/)[1] // => "32322"
s.match(/;([^ ]+)/)[1]              // => "0.25"
s.match(/>(.*?) item listing/i)[1]  // => "Product Name Blah"
```

Comment: Thanks, looks pretty complicated. Ill give it a try and also see is it performs well, and ill pick an answer when im done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**1)**

```
var id = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
id = id.substr(id.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
id = id.substr(0, id.indexOf('-'));
```

**2)**

```
var price = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerText;
price = price.substr(price.indexOf('$') + 1); 
price = price.substr(0, price.indexOf(' '));
```

**3)**

```
var name = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
name = name.substr(name.indexOf('>') + 1);
name = name.substr(0, name.indexOf(' item listing'));
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it and do some comparisons with the regex answer, and see which one i will use. Ill pick an answer after that.

Comment: @SaifBechan see updated answer, please. I integrated the code to your specific html tags. My answer will work with dynamically set values in those tags. As long as the html looks like in the example, just paste the js code to the page and you can extract the correct values.